# Sqlite database on devices without sdcard

Tags: android, sqlite, sd-card

The database file for the devices with sdcard is stored on the sdcard but what happens for the devices which don't have sdcard and have only internal storage like most of the tablets. I have an external database file from which I need the data. Where should I place this file to access it? Given the device does not have an sdcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App's database file is usually located at "/data/data/[package name]/databases/*.db".

Comment: yea but where do I store the database file if I want to access it in my application on a device that doesn't have an sdcard.

Comment: Database's default path is NOT on a sdcard